# MySQL Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I am trying to do a search functionalities that involves three tables.

Searching for users and returning wheather the user id `1` is a friend of the returned users. Also The returned users is being filtered from a third table where it checks tag of that users.

So I can say, "Return users who has tag `'Programming', 'Php'`
 in `userinterests table` and also if the returned user is a friend of `usr id 1` or not "

I am trying to use the bellow query but getting `Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous` 
If I remove the left join then it works.

```
SELECT n.id, n.firstName, n.lastName, t.id, t.tag, t.user_id, if(id in (
        SELECT u.id as id from friends f, users u 
        WHERE CASE 
        WHEN f.following_id=1
        THEN f.follower_id = u.id 
        WHEN f.follower_id=1
        THEN f.following_id = u.id
        END 
        AND
        f.status= 2
    ), "Yes", "No") as isFriend 
FROM users n
LEFT JOIN userinterests t on  n.id = t.id

WHERE t.tag in ('Programming', 'Php')
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: qualify `id` in `... if(id ...` as `t.id` or `n.id`, from whichever table it should be.

Comment: A Case/when in a where in a subquery in select seems to be quite a bad idea.

Comment: One question, do you need on the result query all user that do not have tags `Programming` and `Php`, because if not, you can replace `LEFT JOIN` by `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Ah nice point, the condition has to match so I should use `INNER JOIN` 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify all your column names.  You seem to know this, because all other column names are qualified.

I'm not sure if your logic is correct, but you can fix the error by qualifying the column name:

```
SELECT . . . 
       (CASE WHEN n.id IN (SELECT u.id as id 
                           FROM friends f CROSS JOIN
                                users u 
                           WHERE CASE WHEN f.following_id=1
                                      THEN f.follower_id = u.id 
                                      WHEN f.follower_id=1
                                      THEN f.following_id = u.id
                                 END 
                           ) AND
                 f.status= 2
             THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
        END) as isFriend 
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks, I just corrected my query now working. Could you please explain about your corss join? Is it better than the one I wrote? I tried yours but got error

Comment: Using this give me an error 

`....(CASE WHEN n.id IN (SELECT u.id as id 
                           FROM friends f CROSS JOIN
                                users u 
                           WHERE CASE WHEN f.following_id=1
                                      ........
                                 END 
                           ) AND
                 f.status= 2
             THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
        END) as isFriend FROM users n
..`
gives me `Unknown column 'f.status' in 'field list'`

If I remove `'f.status' ` then it works,.

Comment: @sadek . . . You should be using an explicit `join`.  I wouldn't recommend using a `case` in the `where` clause either.  But your question is about fixing a particular error, not the best way to write the query.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I will go for your approach:

**1)** I used `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` for skip users that are not related to tags: `Programming` and `Php`.

**2)** I replaced the logic to find the set of friends related to user with `id` equal to `1`.

```
SELECT
    n.id,
    n.firstName,
    n.lastName,
    t.id,
    t.tag,
    t.user_id,
    IF(
        n.id IN (SELECT follower_id FROM friends WHERE status = 2 AND following_id = 1
                 UNION
                 SELECT following_id FROM friends WHERE status = 2 AND follower_id = 1),
        "Yes",
        "No"
    ) AS isFriend
FROM
    users n
INNER JOIN
    userinterests t ON n.id = t.id AND t.tag IN ('Programming', 'Php')
```

Just curious, whats is the meaning of `status = 2` ?

Comment: status = 2 mean if user is a friend or in block list.

Comment: One question, if I want to select users if any of the tags matches? Like user can have either `'Programming' or 'Php' ?

Comment: That is just the logic of `IN`, `1 IN (1,2)` will evaluate to `true`, and same will go for `2 IN (1,2)`. Is `tag` column a simple tag or a set of tags?

Comment: tags are dynamic and one can have many tags selected. I am not sure what you meant with 1, 2

Comment: Was just an example with dummy values for show the logic of the operator. In your case `'Php' IN ('Programming', 'Php')` will evaluate to `true`, and `'Programming' IN ('Programming', 'Php')` will also evaluates to `true`. Now, if the column `tag` have multiple tags, like `Programming, C++, Javascript, Php` you can't use `t.tag IN ('Programming', 'Php')`. In this case you will have to use a regular expression: `t.tag REGEXP 'Programming|Php'`